# Select Range of DatetimeIndex Rows Using .loc (Pandas Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series, datetimeindex

Working with a pandas series with DatetimeIndex. 
Desired outcome is a dataframe containing all rows within the range specified within the .loc[] function.

When I try the following code:

```
aapl.index = pd.to_datetime(aapl.index)
print(aapl.loc[pd.Timestamp('2010-11-01'):pd.Timestamp('2010-12-30')])
```

I am returned:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, ExDividend, SplitRatio, 
AdjOpen, AdjHigh, AdjLow, AdjClose, AdjVolume]
Index: []
```

Just to re-iterate, my desired outcome is a subset of the dataframe, containing all rows the are within the range (2010-11-01):(2010-12-30).

Comment: print `aapl.head()` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: @anon, did one of the below solutions help? If so, feel free to accept one (green tick on left), or ask further questions.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you need to convert your index to `datetime`, then use standard indexing / slicing notation.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(365)))

# these lines are for demonstration purposes only
df['date'] = pd.date_range('2010-1-1', periods=365, freq='D').astype(str)
df = df.set_index('date')

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

res = df[pd.Timestamp('2010-11-01'):pd.Timestamp('2010-11-10')]

#               0
# date           
# 2010-11-01  304
# 2010-11-02  305
# 2010-11-03  306
# 2010-11-04  307
# 2010-11-05  308
# 2010-11-06  309
# 2010-11-07  310
# 2010-11-08  311
# 2010-11-09  312
# 2010-11-10  313
```

Answer (score 4):

IIUC:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
aapl = web.get_data_yahoo('aapl')

aapl.loc['2010-11-01':'2010-12-30']
```

Using [partial string indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) and slicing.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity I tried putting the most recent date as the start of the selection, and the less recent date as the end. To my surprise this worked but the Time series data was in reverse order.

In:

```
aapl.loc[pd.Timestamp('2010-12-30'):pd.Timestamp('2010-11-01')]
```

So... duh I realised my Timeseries data must be in reverse order. 
The question now becomes, how do I sort a DatetimeIndex df into the correct order?

Desired order would have nth date as the last row, and the earliest date as the first row.

******EDIT******

```
aapl.index = pd.to_datetime(aapl.index)
aapl =  aapl.sort_index(ascending=True)

aaplrange = aapl.loc[pd.Timestamp('2010-11-01'):pd.Timestamp('2010-12-30')]
```

Works!